# grep of executable commands with variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, output

Have a file with thousands of lines like so :

```
echo " device " ; login 'command' ip > device_command" $(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p")".txt
```

I run my script like so:

```
./script.sh | grep "device"
```

..in order to target specific device. Each line within the script is executable. Question is how do grep it from an other script and EXECUTE the line, not just echo it out.

```
#!/bin/bash
nameFind=$1
grep "$nameFind" script.sh | while read line
do
    "result of grep "
done
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to simply pipe it to a shell:

```
./script.sh | grep "device" | sh
```

Simple example:

```
$ cat input
echo one
echo two
echo three
$ grep t input | sh
two
three
```